# Woocommerce Whatsapp Chat Link Carrying Product Specific Custom Message. Possible?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I have a woocommerce website. My product page template has a button that opens Whatsapp chat. However, I can't identify from which product URL the chat originated.

So my question is, is it possible to create some kind of Javascript class that would carry custom message depending on the URL.

So for example, if the customer presses the Whatsapp button from URL - website.com/product1 - the chat should carry a custom message like "I saw this on website.com/product1. Please provide me a quote"

I don't actually know how to proceed and whether it is techically feasible.

Comment: You can but depends do you use plugin or custom code ? Here is one that have this - https://woocommerce.com/products/quick-whatsapp-chat-and-orders-for-woocommerce/

Comment: Yeah found one plugin. I was wondering whether I can add custom code to a plain vanilla Elementor button.